# If $E e^{\theta ^{2} X^{2}} \leq e^{c\theta^2}$ for every $\theta$, then $X$ is almost surely bounded

Tags: probability, measure-theory, inequality, random-variables, concentration-of-measure

The original problem states as below:

Suppose some random variable $X$ satisfies $\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E e^{\theta ^{2} X^{2}} \leq e^{c\theta^2}$ for some constant $c$ and  $\forall \theta \in R$ show that $X$ is a bounded random variable ? i.e  $\|X\|_{\infty} <\infty$

how to solve this one ?

Here is some of my attempt:

We want to bound $\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}} (\E|X|^p)^{1/p}$

$$
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E|X|^p &= \int_0^\infty P(|X|^p>t)\mathrm{d}t\\
&=  \int_0^\infty P(|X|>t^{1/p})\mathrm{d}t\\
&= \int_0^\infty P(e^{X^2}>e^{t^{2/p}})\mathrm{d}t\\
&\leq \int_0^\infty e^{-t^{2/p}} \E e^{X^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
&\leq e^{c}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^{2/p}} \mathrm{d}t \quad（\E e^{\theta ^{2} X^{2}} \leq e^{c\theta^2},take \  \ \theta=1)\\
&=e^c\Gamma(\frac{2/p+1}{2/p})\\
&\leq e^c (\frac{2+p}{2})^{\frac{2+p}{2}}
\end{align*}
$$

then we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}} 
(\E|X|^p)^{1/p} \leq e^{c/p}(\frac{2+p}{2})^{\frac{2+p}{2p}} 
\end{align*} $$
which do not converges as $ p \to \infty $
,to here I think I fail to bound it

@Clement C. just check your hint , I think it is workable if I compute it right

$$
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}} 
\underset{\theta}{inf} \frac{e^{c\theta^2}}{\theta^p}\Gamma(1+p/2)&= 2(ce)^{p/2}  \frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{p}{2})}{(p/2)^{(p/2)}}
\\ &= 2(ce)^{p/2}\frac{p}{2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{p}{2})}{(p/2)^{(p/2)}}
\\ &\leq (ce)^{p/2}P   
\end{align*} $$

and thus we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}} 
(\E|X|^p)^{1/p} \leq （ce)^{1/2} p^{1/p} \leq (ce)^{1/2} e^{1/e}
\end{align*} $$

which is bound by constant

Comment: Please read my answer also. If I didn't make t a mistake this is really trivial.

Comment: ShaoyuPei: And there is an even more trivial approach... Really, you accept answers much too quickly.

Comment: Additionnally, I would be curious to know if you actually managed to complete the proof @ClementC. suggested...

Comment: @Did Me too, to be honest. My solution (assuming is does go through without further assumptions on $c$) is not the most elegant nor shortest, merely one that mimicks the OP's attempt to fix it.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I got that (that you were trying to follow the approach suggested in the question as much as possible). But: 1. I think that the bound you obtain for $E(|X|^p)^{1/p}$ does not stay bounded when $c\geqslant1$ (not sure, to be checked), 2. I wonder how the OP would conclude if they knew that $E(|X|^p)^{1/p}$ stays bounded. And, since they are still visiting the site, their silence is not a good sign...

Comment: @ShaoyuPei Before accepting my answer, have you managed to make my suggestion go through?

Comment: @Did Indeed. Checking now, as written the minimum appears to be achieved by taking $\theta^2 = p/(2c)$, and the final bound is asymptotically $\sqrt{p\pi} c^{p/2}$. Thus what I wrote only appears to work when $c<1$.

Comment: @ClementC. Exactly. (Kudos for your constructive reaction, not so frequent on the site in similar situations...)

Comment: @Did  honestly  I don't go through Clement C. completely .... I just come back to study these stuff today :( , because his answer is quite like intend approach from textbook ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You are not using the fact that the bound holds *for every $\theta$*. This is important.

To use it: Introduce "artificially" a $\theta$: for every $\theta>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}|X|^p &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\{|X|^p>t\}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=  \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\{|X|>t^{1/p}\}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\{e^{\theta^2 X^2} > e^{\theta^2t^{2/p}}\} dt\\
&\leq \int_0^\infty e^{-\theta^2t^{2/p}} \mathbb{E}[e^{\theta^2 X^2}] dt \tag{Markov}\\
&\leq e^{c\theta^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-\theta^2t^{2/p}}dt \tag{assumption}
\end{align}
Now compute the integral as you did to get a final bound
$$
\frac{e^{c\theta^2}}{\theta^p}\Gamma(1+p/2) \tag{$\dagger$}
$$ which depends on $\theta$; then try to choose the best $\theta$ **as a function of $p$** to optimize this bound.

**Important:** *The above does **not** appear to go through. Namely, the minimum of $(\dagger)$ is achieved for $\theta^2 = p/(2c)$, and the final bound is asymptotically $\sqrt{p\pi} c^{p/2}$. Thus $(\mathbb{E}|X|^p)^{1/p}$ will only be bounded if $0\leq c<1$ (in which case the limit as $p\to\infty$ is $0$).*

Comment: Please see if my answer is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Please see if mine is :)

Comment: @I think your solution is workable

Answer (score 3):

Low-tech approach: For every $\theta$ and every $a>c$, $$E(e^{\theta^2X^2})\geqslant E(e^{\theta^2X^2};X^2\geqslant a)\geqslant e^{\theta^2a}P(X^2\geqslant a)$$ hence $$P(X^2\geqslant a)\leqslant e^{-\theta^2a}e^{\theta^2c}$$ The RHS goes to $0$ when $\theta^2\to\infty$ hence $$P(X^2\geqslant a)=0$$ This holds for every $a>c$ hence $X^2\leqslant c$ almost surely, QED.

Answer (score 2):

We have $Ee^{\theta^{2}(X^{2}-c)} \leq 1$. By Fatou's Lemma $E \lim \inf_{\theta \to \infty} e^{\theta^{2}(X^{2}-c)} \leq 1$. On the set $X^{2} >c$ the $\lim \inf $ is $\infty$. This implies that $X^{2} \leq c$ almost everywhere.